# Select answer automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to eliminate the question and select the answer automatically on the code below (always "approvejob")

```
events: {
        'click .btn_browse_job': 'browseJob',
        'click .btn_approve_job': 'approveJob',
        'click .btn_reject_job': 'rejectJob',
        'click .btn_show_tasks': 'showTasks',
        'change select': 'action'
       },

      template: _.template($('#job-template').html()),

      render: function()
        {
          $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

          $(this.el).css(
            'background-color', 
            this.getStatusColor(this.model.get('currentstep'))
          );

          // Micro-services requiring approval
          if (1 === this.model.get('status'))
          {
            this.$('.job-detail-actions')
             .append('<a class="btn_browse_job" href="#" title="Browse"><span>Browse</span></a>')
              .append('<a class="btn_approve_job" href="#" title="Approve"><span>Approve</span></a>')
              .append('<a class="btn_reject_job" href="#" title="Reject"><span>Reject</span></a>');
          }
          else
          {
            // ...
          }

          choices = this.model.get('choices');

          if (choices)
          {
           var $select = $('<select />').append('<option>Actions/option>')
           , numberOfChoices = Object.keys(choices).length
              , optionHtml;

            // use pop-up action selector for long choice lists
            if (numberOfChoices >= 10)
            {
              var statusObject = {};
              this.activateEnhancedActionSelect($select, statusObject);
            }

            for (var code in choices)
            {
              optionHtml = '<option value="' + code + '">- ' + choices[code] + '</option>';
              $select.append(optionHtml);
            }

            this.$('.job-detail-actions').append($select);
          }

          this.$('.job-detail-microservice > a').tooltip();

          return this;
        },

      action: function(event)
        {
          var value = $(event.target).val()
            , self = this;

          $.ajax({
            context: this,
            data: { uuid: this.model.get('uuid'), choice: value, uid: this.uid },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data)
              {
                this.model.set({
                  'currentstep': 'Executing command(s)',
                  'status': 0
                });

                this.model.sip.view.updateIcon();

                // get rid of select, etc.
                self.$('.job-detail-actions').empty();
              },
            url: '/mcp/execute/'
          });
        }

    });

    window.DirectoryBrowserView = BaseDirectoryBrowserView.extend({
      template: _.template($('#directory-browser-template').html())
    });

    window.AppView = BaseAppView.extend({
      el: $('#sip-container'),
      pagingCookie: 'archivematicaCurrentTransferPage'
    });

    $.fn.tooltip = tooltipPlugin;
    window.onresize = optimizeWidth;
    window.onload = optimizeWidth;
  }
);
```

Comment: What does "eliminate the question" mean? Actually, what does any of your question mean? Can you give an example?